# redirect loop error laravel auth

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi im trying to make a good user auth form but i ve have had some problems , so first i tried this :

```
Route::get('login', function()
{
    /* Get the login form data using the 'Input' class */
    $userdata = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    /* Try to authenticate the credentials */
    if(Auth::attempt($userdata))
    {
        // we are now logged in, go to admin
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
});
```

and this is the form blade page :

```
     {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="username"></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="password"></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-inverse"></button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
```

and it gave me the redirect loop error

and then i tried this :

```
Route::get('login', function()
{
    /* Get the login form data using the 'Input' class */
    $user = new User;
    $log = array(
    $user -> username =  Input::get('username'),
    $user -> password =  Input::get('password')
    );



    /* Try to authenticate the credentials */
    if(Auth::attempt($log))
    {
        // we are now logged in, go to admin
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
});
```

and it gives me :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `0` is null and `1` is null limit 1)
```

does anyone knows whats the problem?
first code should have worked perfectly but why redirect error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstfully, change your route names, to:
 `Route::get('login', function(){});` And `Route::get('sign-in', function(){});`

**Get auth page:**

```
Route::get('login', function()
{
   return View::make('your-auth-view');
}
```

**And your `sign-in` handler should looks like:**

```
Route::get('sign-in', function(){
    $userdata = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

     if(Auth::attempt($userdata))
    {
        // we are now logged in, go to admin
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
});
```

**And form will change to**:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'sign-in', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
```

P.S. You have a redirect loop, because, you have a two the same routes, and when you submit the form you redirect to login page again and again

Comment: hi , thanks for your answer i dont get no error but the problem is it cant find my user name and password form the database and it keeps redirecting me to login page 
i have replaced : your-auth-view' wiht 'login' 
and my data base has lots of columns but 2 of them are username and password , it cant find the in the database or the code has in depth problem?

Comment: my user model is laravel's default..
users table - > along other colums id , first name and... there is username and password colum.

Comment: If you are have not changed auth config, Auth::attempt($userdata) should work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 4.2 and still have issues after adding

`{{ Form::token() }}` or

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">`

Then you can try changing the `filter.php` file in app directory by adding

`Request::getMethod() !== 'GET'` on your filter.

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
  if (Request::getMethod() !== 'GET' && Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
 {
  throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
 }
});
```

This has been useful to me too.